# Maxmind Lat/Lon Values

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude

I am no expert when it comes to maps, but does anyone know which map type the latitude and longitude values provided with the (free) MaxMind database of cities belong to? Are they a Miller cylindrical projection, Mercator projection or any of the other map types (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Cylindrical)?

Comment: Latitude and longitude represent un-projected positions on the Earth's surface.  When you want to map the location of a city, then you project it using Mercator, Lambert, gnomonic, whatever, onto a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mark said, the latitude and longitude values are generic. Depending on the projection you transform them appropriately.